# Linked list, Struct, Dynamic memory allocation

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

```
Struct node
{ char name [30];
int length;
node * next;
};
```

Using dynamic memory allocation how will i use the struct above to create a list to hold any number of nodes? without knowing that number beforehand.

Comment: answer is in your question itself. Use linked list

Comment: you just add them one at a time when you need

Comment: i suppose i am not understanding the topic then could someone give me an example?

Comment: 1. should be `struct` with a lowercase S, 2. if you are doing `C++`, try `std::string` instead of `char [30]`, make it a `class`, add constructor and methods, etc.

Comment: I would suggest that you find a nice book on data structures and/or basic C++ to move forward.

Answer (score 0):

Please read through this simple and quick [tutorial](http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/lesson15.html) on Singly linked lists in C++